# capture Second mouse movement

Tags: c#, mouse

I have 2 mice. My goal is to use one for pointing and the other for something else (launching applications or etc). I want to capture my second mouse events not my first mouse. So afar I can capture both mice events but not them separately.

Comment: you have 2 mice on the same computer? That normally doesn't work well. Could you explain a little more clearly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: well sorry my English is like it is. I want to capture my second mouse events not my first mouse. So afar i can capture both mice events but not them separately.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about this but check this out if it helps.

> Microsoft MultiPoint Software
>   Development Kit (SDK) is a development
>   framework that allows developers to
>   build applications that enable up to
>   250 individual mouse devices to work
>   simultaneously on one computer.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f851122a-4925-4788-bc39-409644ce0f9b&displaylang=en

Comment: +1 cool find "MultiPoint is a development framework that enables developers to build applications to take advantage of multiple mouse devices, including the ability to handle mouse clicks from different users independently and to assign different permissions to each mouse."

Comment: @Shoban: that looks really interesting!

Comment: I did a search and found this ;-) i was confused first time seeing this question but found it interesting when I read 250 mouse in 1 pc ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I also have two pointing devices connected to the computer, but inside the c# code, there is no way to tell which one of them that produced the input. I can for instance use one of them for moving the mouse, while using the buttons of the other one and perform drag-drop operations.

So you have no choice but to let your program believe in what it sees; that there is only one mouse.